# program that switches from first name then last name to last name then first name. Can you help fix pls?

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error "conflicting variable is defined below" at firstName and lastName.

Also 'local variable firstName is never used, a local variable named firstName cannot be declared in this scope.... etc'

edit = this isn't homework, just an exercise in the book I'm using.

http://pastebin.com/zNiuUCkd

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MethodsPractice
{
class Program
{
     static string SwitchName(string x, string y)
     {

         string firstName = x;
         string lastName = y;

         string temp = firstName;

        firstName = lastName;
        lastName = temp;

        string final = ("{0},{1}", firstName, lastName)



        return final;

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nameReversed = "";
        string first = "Tim";
        string last = "Stern";
        nameReversed = SwitchName(first, last);

        Console.WriteLine(nameReversed);
        Console.ReadKey(true);

    }


   }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Post your code, not a link to your code.

Comment: Can you include code inline rather than requiring people to use external resources? Ta.

Comment: Where is ";" after `string final = ("{0},{1}", firstName, lastName)`?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the point of this code? It seems like a very long-winded way to perform a very simple action.

Comment: @AdrianWragg how would you do it easier?

Comment: @user2723261 Another answer gives a much more succinct version (I put similar in mine, then removed it when I noticed to avoid suggestions of plagiarism). I've also suggested renaming the function.

Answer (score 6):

Or

```
 static string SwitchName(string firstname, string lastname)
 {
    return String.Format("{0},{1}", lastname, firstName)
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is in the following line:

```
string final = ("{0},{1}", firstName, lastName)
```

I suspect what you require is actually the following instead:

```
string final = String.Format("{0},{1}", firstName, lastName);
```

which avoids the errors you mention.

Note that your entire procedure could just be rewritten, as another answer has already mentioned. I would also strongly suggest renaming it; `SwitchName` does not reflect the functionality of the procedure.